# Breaking down a conditional probability into a marginal probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayesian

I was reading [this blog post](https://www.behind-the-enemy-lines.com/2008/01/are-you-bayesian-or-frequentist-or.html) on using Bayesian statistics to obtain the probability of 2 heads in a row for a coin toss, given that 14 tosses resulted in 10 heads.

I am confused on how the highlighted step in the image was obtained on the page. If anyone could clarify or prove the equality, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am confused on how the highlighted step in the image was obtained on the page. If anyone could clarify or prove the equality, I'd really appreciate it.

First observe that

$$\mathbb{P}[HH,p|\text{data}]=\mathbb{P}[HH|p,\text{data}]\cdot\mathbb{P}[p|\text{data}]$$

now considering the assumption they made of conditional independence (w.r.t. the parameter  $p$) of the observations you get

$$\mathbb{P}[HH,p|\text{data}]=\mathbb{P}[HH|p]\cdot\mathbb{P}[p|\text{data}]$$

At this point, to eliminate $p$ in the left member you have to integrate both members in $dp$ obtaining

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
\mathbb{P}[HH|\text{data}]=\int_0^1\mathbb{P}[HH|p]\cdot\mathbb{P}[p|\text{data}]dp
\
}
$$

Observe that inside the integral you have

$$\underbrace{\mathbb{P}[HH|p]}_{=\text{model}}\cdot\underbrace{\mathbb{P}[p|\text{data}]}_{=\text{Posterior Distribution}}$$

Comment: Thanks very much!